# How to match a string pattern in PHP like (Volume 1, Book 2, Number 8:)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What will be regular expression to use in preg_match() function for string **Volume 1, Book 2, Number 8:** the integer 1,2,8 will change for multiple  occurrence of this string.

Comment: Please at least try to learn the basics of regular expressions... This just requires you to know how to say "any digit": `\d` or `[0-9]` or `[0123456789]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
/Volume (\d+), Book (\d+), Number (\d+)/
```

And the big benefit is that those () mark these as values you can retrieve later.

Answer (score 0):

use `[0-9]` when checking for digits using regex.

If your digits are between 0 and 9 use

```
preg_match("Volume [0-9], Book [0-9], Number [0-9]", $string)
```

Comment: You'll want to have a + after the [] notation, so that you also catch "Number 10" and the like.

Comment: @Wolfman Joe You mean to do this preg_match("Volume [0-9]+, Book [0-9]+, Number [0-9]+", $string); to catch number greater then 10?

Comment: @Kalim, `[0-9]+` matches any number any number of times, so any number from 0 upwards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict those numbers to one digit: `Volume \d, Book \d, Number \d:`

If you want to accomodate higher numbers: `Volume \d+, Book \d+, Number \d+:`

Whats going on: `\d` is a regex code that matches any single digit. `+` denotes that the previous character should appear 1 or more times. So, `\d+` will match one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to regexp:

```
list($volume, $book, $number) = sscanf($string, "Volume %d, Book %d, Number %d");
```